# mod_rewrite partial URI match returning 404

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^media/assets/([^\/]*).js$ /content.php?lang=js&code=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^media/assets/([^\/]*).css$ /content.php?lang=css&code=$1 [L]
```

I'm getting 404 error on these rules, What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing the resource; that's what 404 means . . .

Comment: @LeviMorrison please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^assets/content/(.*)\.(.*)/$ /content.php?code=$1&lang=$2 [L]
```